# Windows Phone (7.1) "skinning" based on user's current theme

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, themes, windows-phone, skinning

In short my questions are: How to switch ResourceDictionaries in a WP7.1 app? Is there an easier way than the one I am trying to do?

Details...

In a Windows Phone 7 project I need to replace the application resources according to the user's theme (light/dark). The idea in a nutshell is obvious:
        a) create a ResourceDictionary variable
        b) get the appropriate styles and brushes resource files according to the current theme
        c) add the above resources to the Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries

Here's what I am doing:

1) Folder structure for resources in the "View" project: 
    Resources
        Dark
            Brushes.xaml 
            Styles.xaml
        Light
            Brushes.xaml 
            Styles.xaml

2) The styles in the 2 Brushes.xaml files have the same Keys. Same with Styles.xaml.

3) In my first attempt (assuming light theme selected) I get an "unspecified error" on the second line.

```cs
var uriPath = "Resources/Light/Brushes.xaml"; 
var brushes = new ResourceDictionary {Source = new Uri(uriPath, UriKind.Relative)};
dic.MergedDictionaries.Add(brushes);
```

(FYI I tried with Resource, Page and Content build actions)

4) My second attempt gives me hope, as I successfully manage to stuff Brushes.xaml into the App's MergedDictionaries:

```cs
string xaml;
var uriPath = "Resources/Light/Brushes.xaml";
var brushesUri = new Uri(uriPath, UriKind.Relative);
var brushesStream = Application.GetResourceStream(brushesUri);
using (var brushesStreamReader = new StreamReader(brushesStream.Stream))
    xaml = brushesStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
var dic = new ResourceDictionary();
dic.MergedDictionaries.Add((ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(xaml));
```

5) In order for brushesStreamReader to not be `null` in the code above I have to set the xaml files to "Content". (why?)

6) The second problem with my code in step 4 is when attempting to do the same thing with Styles.xaml. I get a "`Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source'`" on the last line (dic.MergedDictionaries.Add...). Perhaps this is because Styles.xaml adds Brushes.xaml to its own MergedDictionaries:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Brushes.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Is it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In that case you could just grab the theme brush and analyze it. Ex:

```
private Color lightThemeBackground = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255); 
private Color darkThemeBackground = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0);  


public bool IsLightTheme()
{
     SolidColorBrush backgroundBrush = Application.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;   
     if (backgroundBrush.Color == lightThemeBackground) { 
          // you are in the light theme
          return true;
     } 
     else { 
          // you are in the dark theme
          return false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have to do this. Just use the system brushes to get all the theme colors.
Here's a good overview of these brushes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769552.aspx#BKMK_BrushResources

Comment: thanks but this doesn't answer my question. Using system brushes is very limited. What if you want to show different animations, or render your controls differently according to the themes? Or simply, what if you want to show all the accents of your visual elements with shades of red when in "light" mode and other palette when in "Dark" mode?